# Unoconv - Maintain scaling converting xlsx to pdf

Tags: excel, pdf, xlsx, xls, unoconv

I'm using unoconv to convert an Excel file to PDF.  The converted PDF retains the correct scaling when converting from an .xls file, however the PDF scaling reverts to 100% when converting from an .xlsx file.  In other words, unoconv converts the same file, albeit with different extensions and Excel format, differently.

Operating system is Ubuntu. I'm running unoconv from the command line. I've scoured the web for a solution and have found none. I believe it's a bug in unoconv, i.e. unoconv does not seem to support maintaining the scaling when converting from .xlsx as it does when converting from .xls

Has anyone else encountered this and, if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert .xlsx files directly from Excel

File>Save As > Browse. change file extension to pdf from drop down menu.

or
File>Save as Adobe PDF and follow the dialog

this is at Office 2013

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit.  I'm running unoconv from the command line in Ubuntu.

Comment: No problem, I hope You'll figure it out.